# Can't log in to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: login

I can't log in to my ubuntu 12.04. Once I login I got returned back to the original screen after a trial to enable X11 Forwarding.

Can you help me with this.

Comment: Are you trying to login remotely? What did you do to try to enable X11 forwarding?

Comment: Does this only happen when trying to log in remotely? Or are you having this problem logging in locally as well?

Comment: Check your .xsession-errors in your home directory, I found an error over there, fixed it, then I can login from desktop. I did try to change the permission and ownership of .Xauthority but it doesn't help in my case.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried to enable X11Forwarding, but I used to have the same problem. You can fix this in a few steps:

- When you get to the graphical login screen, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, thus you get to a textual login.
- Put in your name and password (password is not displayed when you type, neither as stars or bullets).
- Type `sudo apt-get install gdm` and hit enter, give your password and wait to get a line ending with a dollar sign again.
- Type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`.
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the first screen.
- Select `gdm` in the list you get in the second screen with the arrow keys.
- Hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button (above the caps lock one). Now you see the word Ok highlighted. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Type `sudo reboot` and hit enter. You'll get another graphical login screen, but you'll be able to log in!

P.S.:

1. If you are used to running some programs like `ifconfig` or others which are administrative ones from a terminal emulator (e.g. gnome-terminal) you'd better add a line like `PATH="$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin"` at the end of the `.bashrc` file in your home directory. You can do it with `echo 'PATH="$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin"' >> ~/.bashrc`.
2. If you want to change back to the other graphical login screen from time to time and see if it was bug-fixed and it works again you can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and select `lightdm` and reboot (doesn't look like it works if you just run `sudo pkill X`).

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue after installing package `vnc4server` in Ubuntu 12.10.  (Maybe it sets up X11 forwarding, not sure.)  I found that in my home directory, files `.Xauthority`, `.bash_history` and folder `.vnc` were all owned by user `root` and group `root`.  Changing them (and all files underneath `.vnc`) to be owned by my own user with the `chown` command allowed me to login (I rebooted first).

To make these corrections, either ssh into the box from elsewhere or switch to text console with Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Comment: I had just `~/.Xauthority` as `root` owner. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I found out my problem was related to a messy package repository. I updated my repositories and reinstalled ubuntu-desktop:

- Log in to bash, (Ctrl+Alt+F1)

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Solved.

Comment: I've tried the other solutions but did not work for me. This worked, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is an error in your .bashrc or .profile file.  From the graphical login screen hit Ctrl+Alt+F2 and login from there.  Fix any errors that you see printed to the console.  Type: sudo reboot

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: .bashrc isn't sourced from a login shell like the one you get from the TTY console.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when I accidentally used:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I found that it had removed ubuntu-desktop for some reason. You can try Ctrl+Alt+F1 and use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

After it has finished, press Ctrl+Alt+F7 and login as usual. Mine was still lacking the Restart and User accounts buttons on the panel; for that, go to terminal and use:

```
unity --reset
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .xsession-errors file in the home dir for any errors after logging in via CTRL+ALT+F1

In my case, .xsession-errors showed an error saying I had bad characters in my .profile file from my git installation(human error.. my bad)

After I fixed the error in my .profile file, I was able to login via the login GUI

Comment #18 at the below link helped me.
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+question/197479

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that somehow due to manipulations with SSD, permissions of /tmp were messed up and I found on some Ubuntu forum this solution which helped me:

```
chmod 777 /tmp
chmod +t /tmp
sudo chown root:root /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me a couple of times and each time I restarted the Display Manager and could log in.

Drop to tty1 with Ctrl-Alt-F1.

sudo service lightdm restart

Answer (score -1):

Log in to bash, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

```
$passwd
$newpasswd
$newpasswd
```

You are good to go now!
that's what solved my issue.