# Can't login to Ubuntu 12.04 [Also ctrl+ alt+f2 not working], keeps rebouncing to same login page

Tags: 12.04, login

When i try to login to my account i cannot login. It keeps re-bouncing to the same login page and it doesn't show wrong password. I when i type a wrong password it does show "Wrong Password". So i checked the problem in this site found an answer :[Can't log in to ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139528/cant-log-in-to-ubuntu-12-04) .

As the answer says i tried **ctrl+alt+f2** , it doesn't work and there isn't any response. I tried out ctrl+alt+__ and all possible yet no change.
The Ubuntu that i use is a fresh install and not any upgrades. I logged into Guest account and tried out ctrl+alt+F1 and there isn't any response. Can someone help me?

Comment: I already wrote in the post that ctrl + alt +F1 isn't working.

Comment: But, if you can login into guest account, I assume that you can open a [Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) where you can run commands.

Comment: I cannot use sudo in guest account.

Comment: Also I tried it with root terminal from recovery mode. I did as specified by the post you mentioned. It says permission of directory changed but still I have the same problem.